# How to get information when is connected to web site?

Tags: c++, windows, web, connect

I want to set focus to search form on site http://www.filehippo.com/, and after that send some text (for example some application name what want to download).

But before that need to be shore if computer is connected to site. So now my question is **how to implement some kind of listener who will wait for specific ip address of site**, and after computer is connected get back information?

Only problem is that I develop in visual studio c++ and searching answer for those language, know that c++ is not best solution for task's like that but this is just one part of application and at now don't have time to study other language.

Os: WIN 7, 64, Visual studio 2010 c++

Comment: You have to know that, unless you have control over this website or it provides some kind of webservice, everything you will come up with will be unreliable at best.

Comment: Also, don't rely on the site IP address: IP addresses can change, and a website may use several servers (which have different addresses). That is one of the reasons DNS exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using [WinINet API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385331%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in order to access web services (HTTP POST) and download files hosted on web server (HTTP GET). It contains functions to connect to specific web site (e.g. [InternetConnect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384363%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)), send and receive requests etc. so you might find it useful.